# Problem while training UR on PredictionIO

Tags: predictive-modeling, apache-spark

Fallowing this tutorial https://templates.prediction.io/PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-universal-recommendation, when trying to train I get the fallowing error message

```
[ERROR] [TaskSetManager] Task 0 in stage 23.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 23.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 23.0 (TID 17, localhost): java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.apache.mahout.math.DenseVector.<init>(DenseVector.java:57)
    at org.apache.mahout.sparkbindings.SparkEngine$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkEngine.scala:78)
     at org.apache.mahout.sparkbindings.SparkEngine$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkEngine.scala:77)
     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:706)
     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:706)
     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
     at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1283)
     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
     at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1496)
     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1447)
     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1822)
     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1942)
     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1.apply(RDD.scala:1003)
     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.reduce(RDD.scala:985)
     at org.apache.mahout.sparkbindings.SparkEngine$.numNonZeroElementsPerColumn(SparkEngine.scala:86)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.drm.CheckpointedOps.numNonZeroElementsPerColumn(CheckpointedOps.scala:37)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.cf.SimilarityAnalysis$.sampleDownAndBinarize(SimilarityAnalysis.scala:286)
     at org.apache.mahout.math.cf.SimilarityAnalysis$.cooccurrences(SimilarityAnalysis.scala:66)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.cf.SimilarityAnalysis$.cooccurrencesIDSs(SimilarityAnalysis.scala:141)
     at a.test.URAlgorithm.calcAll(URAlgorithm.scala:143)
     at a.test.URAlgorithm.train(URAlgorithm.scala:117)
     at a.test.URAlgorithm.train(URAlgorithm.scala:102)
     at io.prediction.controller.P2LAlgorithm.trainBase(P2LAlgorithm.scala:46)
     at io.prediction.controller.Engine$$anonfun$18.apply(Engine.scala:688)
    at io.prediction.controller.Engine$$anonfun$18.apply(Engine.scala:688)
     at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
     at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
     at io.prediction.controller.Engine$.train(Engine.scala:688)
     at io.prediction.controller.Engine.train(Engine.scala:174)
     at io.prediction.workflow.CoreWorkflow$.runTrain(CoreWorkflow.scala:65)
     at io.prediction.workflow.CreateWorkflow$.main(CreateWorkflow.scala:247)
     at io.prediction.workflow.CreateWorkflow.main(CreateWorkflow.scala)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.apache.mahout.math.DenseVector.<init>(DenseVector.java:57)
    at org.apache.mahout.sparkbindings.SparkEngine$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkEngine.scala:78)
     at org.apache.mahout.sparkbindings.SparkEngine$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkEngine.scala:77)
     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:706)
     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:706)
     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
     at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I configure HBase properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens with me when I'm trying to train with no events for a given event specified in `engine.json` .
Check your `engine.json` to find which *eventNames* you're expecting and make sure that you have imported at least one event for each.

If you're following the template tutorial, you're importing your data with :

`python examples/import_handmade.py`

Make sure to run this command before training your model.

Some commands I use to debug issues with pio that could be helpful :

- `pio export --appid {your_app_id} --output ./data.out` Dumps all app events in JSON to data.out directory
- `pio import --appid {your_app_id} --input ./data/test_data.json` Imports events from test_data in JSON format
- `pio status` Lets you know if everything is running
- `pio app data-delete {your_app_name}` Deletes all data stored by app (Helpful if you want to debug a subset of data)

In your case try exporting the data to make sure there's nothing missing then delete the data, import the new set, and train.